# Local stack DynamoDB is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb

I am tring to  test my AWS resources locally. I found a very nice docker image which has almost all the serives avaible and same can be used for local testing. One of the services for DynamoDB is not working. This is also for my application.

I google it a lot, but I am not able to find the root cause. As per my docker container logs. Below are the logs.

```
docker run -it -p 4567-4578:4567-4578 -p 8080:8080 localstack/localstack
```

> 2018-07-30T12:49:17:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: expected string or buffer Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 181, in forward
>           path=path, data=data, headers=forward_headers)
>         File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/dynamodb/dynamodb_listener.py", line 35, in forward_request
>       TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using wrong port. The answer can be find in localstack's issue list: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/675

The DynamoDB's GUI in localstack is running on port 4564. Run following command, then you are able to access the GUI on localhost:4564/shell

```
docker run -d -p 4569:4569 -p 4564:4564 localstack/localstack:latest
```

connection code

```
const dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

dynamoose.local('http://localhost:4569');

dynamoose.AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
});
const Purchase = dynamoose.model('test', {
  test: {
    type: String,
    hashKey: true,
  }
}, {
  update: true,
});
```

Comment: That is a GUI part but if i have to push data to the database using my java application which end poing should i use.

Comment: That is not working.Already tried that. Please find the above erros in my question.

Comment: AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
   new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8080", "us-west-1"))
   .build(); 
 
 
  DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
  TableCollection<ListTablesResult> table = dynamoDB.listTables();
  
  System.out.println("hello" +table.getMaxResultSize());       It is giving me null i have two tables in my database

Comment: I have tried localhost:4569 with node.js orm dynamoose. It works which means the service itself does not have any problem. The error messages shows because you are using a wrong port. If you still meet the same problem, it should be your code's problem. I don't know how it works in JAVA, and I don't know why you use localhost:8080 in you code.